# How to dispaly custom date of birth field data on the time of chekout in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to display a custom user data field (Date of birth) in checkout page in woocommerce.

I added a custom date of birth field in  my account registration form (image attached)

[image]

I added this with the following custom code in form-login.php via child theme at the given path \childtheme\woocommerce\myaccount\form-login.php

```
        <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="reg_dob"><?php _e( 'Date of Birth', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text" name="reg_customer_dob" id="reg_customer_dob"  value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['reg_customer_dob'] ) ) echo esc_attr_e( $_POST['reg_customer_dob'] ); ?>"/>
        </p>
```

Complete code of form-login.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Login Form
 *
 * This template overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/form-login.php.
 *
 * I added new custom code for regsitration here.
 * Task ID - https://taritas.anywhereapp.io/app/boards/666?taskId=16121
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version 4.1.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_customer_login_form' ); ?>

<?php if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_myaccount_registration' ) ) : ?>

<div class="u-columns col2-set" id="customer_login">

    <div class="u-column1 col-1">

<?php endif; ?>

        <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Login', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

        <form class="woocommerce-form woocommerce-form-login login" method="post">

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form_start' ); ?>

            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="username"><?php esc_html_e( 'Username or email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="username" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['username'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
            </p>
            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="password"><?php esc_html_e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" type="password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="current-password" />
            </p>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form' ); ?>

            <p class="form-row">
                <label class="woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox woocommerce-form-login__rememberme">
                    <input class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox" name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" /> <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Remember me', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span>
                </label>
                <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-login', 'woocommerce-login-nonce' ); ?>
                <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-button button woocommerce-form-login__submit" name="login" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Log in', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Log in', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
            </p>
            <p class="woocommerce-LostPassword lost_password">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wp_lostpassword_url() ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Lost your password?', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
            </p>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form_end' ); ?>

        </form>

<?php if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_myaccount_registration' ) ) : ?>

    </div>

    <div class="u-column2 col-2">

        <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

        <form method="post" class="woocommerce-form woocommerce-form-register register" <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_tag' ); ?> >

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start' ); ?>

            <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_username' ) ) : ?>

                <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                    <label for="reg_username"><?php esc_html_e( 'Username', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="reg_username" autocomplete="username" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['username'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
                </p>

                <?php endif; ?>

                <p class="form-row form-row-first">
                <label for="reg_billing_first_name"><?php _e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_first_name" id="reg_billing_first_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ); ?>" />
                </p>

                <p class="form-row form-row-last">
                <label for="reg_billing_last_name"><?php _e( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_last_name" id="reg_billing_last_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ); ?>" />
                </p>

                <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="reg_dob"><?php _e( 'Date of Birth', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="input-text" name="reg_customer_dob" id="reg_customer_dob"  value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['reg_customer_dob'] ) ) echo esc_attr_e( $_POST['reg_customer_dob'] ); ?>"/>
                </p>

                <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="reg_email"><?php esc_html_e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="email" id="reg_email" autocomplete="email" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['email'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['email'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
                </p>

                <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="reg_billing_email_cnfrm"><?php _e( 'Please Confirm Email Address ', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_email_cnfrm" id="reg_billing_email_cnfrm" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_email_cnfrm'] ) ) echo esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_email_cnfrm'] ); ?>"  />
                </p>

                <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) ) : ?>

                <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="reg_password"><?php esc_html_e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="password" id="reg_password" autocomplete="new-password" />
                </p>

                <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="confirm_password"><?php esc_html_e( 'Confirm Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="user_password_again" id="confirm_password" autocomplete="confirm-password" />
                </p>

                <?php else : ?>

                <p><?php esc_html_e( 'A password will be sent to your email address.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

                <?php endif; ?>

                <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="reg_billing_phone"><?php _e( 'Mobile', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_phone" id="reg_billing_phone" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) echo esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_phone'] ); ?>"   />
                </p>

                
                <div class="clear"></div>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form' ); ?>

            <p class="woocommerce-form-row form-row">
                <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-register', 'woocommerce-register-nonce' ); ?>
                <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button woocommerce-button button woocommerce-form-register__submit" name="register" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
            </p>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_end' ); ?>

        </form>

    </div>

</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_customer_login_form' ); ?>
```

And validating the above filed at the woocommerce_process_registration_errors hook. The validation code is -

```
   function wooc_validate_extra_register_fields( $validation_errors,$username, $password,$email ) {
   

    if ( isset( $_POST['reg_customer_dob'] ) && empty( $_POST['reg_customer_dob'] ) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'reg_customer_dob_error', __( 'Date of birth cannot be left blank.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }

    if ( empty( $email ) || ! is_email( $email ) ) {
        //return new WP_Error( 'registration-error-invalid-email', __( 'Email address provided is invalid', 'woocommerce' ) );
        error_log("Email address provided is invalid - " . $email);
        $validation_errors->add( 'email_not_match_error', __( 'Email address provided is invalid', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }

    /*
    if ( $_POST['billing_email_cnfrm']  != $_POST['email']  ) {
        //$_POST['eamil'] Default eamil filed
        $validation_errors->add( 'email_not_match_error', __( 'Confirm Email address does not match.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    */

    /** Below Code added becouse code conflict in my account/Registration & chekout page/regsitration  */

    if(isset($_POST['billing_email']))
    {
        if($_POST['billing_email_cnfrm']  != $_POST['billing_email'])
        {//$_POST['billing_email']  email filed in checkout page
            error_log("Confirm Email address does not match AT checkout page for- " . $_POST['billing_email_cnfrm'] ."And User Email - " . $_POST['billing_email']);
            $validation_errors->add( 'email_not_match_error', __( 'Confirm Email address does not match.', 'woocommerce' ) );

        }
    }

    if( isset($_POST['email']))
    {

        if ( email_exists( $email ) ) {
            error_log("An account already exists using this email address - " . $email);
            $validation_errors->add( 'woocommerce_registration_error_email_exists', __( 'An account already exists using this email address, please use a different email address.', 'woocommerce' ) );
        }

        if ( $_POST['billing_email_cnfrm']  != $_POST['email']  ) {
            //$_POST['eamil']  email filed in Myaccount regisration page
            error_log("Confirm Email address does not match at registration page - " . $_POST['billing_email_cnfrm'] ."And User Email - " . $_POST['email']);
            $validation_errors->add( 'email_not_match_error', __( 'Confirm Email address does not match.', 'woocommerce' ) );
        }
    }

    /** End of above Code -- added becouse code conflict in my account/Registration & chekout page/regsitration  */

    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_email_cnfrm'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_email_cnfrm'] ) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'confirm_email_error', __( 'Confirm email address cannot be left blank.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    
    if ( empty( $password ) ) {
        //return new WP_Error( 'registration-error-missing-password', __( 'Password cannot be left blank.', 'woocommerce' ) );
        error_log("Password cannot be left blank.");
        $validation_errors->add( 'confirm_password_error', __( 'Password cannot be left blank.', 'woocommerce' ) );

    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['user_password_again'] ) && empty( $_POST['user_password_again'] ) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'confirm_password_error', __( 'Confirm password cannot be left blank.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }


    /*
    if ( $_POST['user_password_again']  != $_POST['password']  ) {
        //$_POST['password'] Default password filed
        $validation_errors->add( 'password_not_match_error', __( 'Passwords do not match.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }*/

    /** Below Code added becouse code conflict in my account/Registration & chekout page/regsitration  */

    if(isset($_POST['account_password'] ))
    {
        if ( $_POST['user_password_again']  != $_POST['account_password']  ) {
            //$_POST['account_password'] Default password filed in Checkout page
           error_log("Confirm Passwords do not match. at Checkout page - FOR" . $_POST['billing_email_cnfrm'] ."And User Email - " . $_POST['email']);
           $validation_errors->add( 'password_not_match_error', __( 'Passwords do not match.', 'woocommerce' ) );

        }
    }
    if(isset($_POST['password'] ))
    {
        if ( $_POST['user_password_again']  != $_POST['password']  ) {
            //$_POST['account_password'] Default password filed in Myaccount regstration page
            error_log("Confirm Passwords do not match. at registration page - FOR" . $_POST['billing_email_cnfrm'] ."And User Email - " . $_POST['email']);
            $validation_errors->add( 'password_not_match_error', __( 'Passwords do not match.', 'woocommerce' ) );
         }
    }

    /** End of above Code -- added becouse code conflict in my account/Registration & chekout page/regsitration */
   
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'billing_mobile_number_error', __( 'Mobile number cannot be left blank.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }

    if(!validate_mobile($_POST['billing_phone']))
    {
        $validation_errors->add( 'billing_mobile_number_error', __( 'Mobile number entry is numerical only and cannot contain any spaces.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }


    return $validation_errors;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_process_registration_errors', 'wooc_validate_extra_register_fields', 10, 4 );
```

And saving this custom field in usermeta table at woocommerce_created_customer hook .The saving code is

```
function wooc_save_extra_register_fields( $customer_id ) {

    $the_user = get_user_by( 'id', $customer_id ); 

    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) {
                 // Phone input filed which is used in WooCommerce
                 update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_phone', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) );
    }
  
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) {
             //First name field which is by default
             update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'first_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) );
             // First name field which is used in WooCommerce
             update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_first_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) );
    }
    
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) {
             // Last name field which is by default
             update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'last_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) );
             // Last name field which is used in WooCommerce
             update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_last_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) );
    }
    
    if ( isset( $_POST['reg_customer_dob'] ) ) {
            // Phone input filed which is used in WooCommerce
            update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'customer_dob', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['reg_customer_dob'] ) );
    }
   
    update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'new_reg_policy', '1');


}
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'wooc_save_extra_register_fields' );
```

And data is saving to DB (image attached)

[image]

> But after the login at the time of checkout, field is not displaying in checkout form.How can i display that custom DoB Field in the checkout form.I added the image for checkout page

[image]

I added custom date of birth field in check out form via the following code -

```
   add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_checkout_form_fields');
function custom_woocommerce_checkout_form_fields( $fields )
{
    $fields['billing']['reg_customer_dob'] = array(
        'label'       => __('Date of Birth', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field label
        'placeholder' => __('Date of Birth', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field placeholder
        'required'    => true, // if field is required or not
        'clear'       => false, // add clear or not
        'type'        => 'text', // add field type
        'class'       => array('form-row form-row-wide'),   // add class name
        'priority'    => 25, // Priority sorting option
    );

    $fields['account']['billing_email_cnfrm'] = array(
        'label'       => __('Confirm Email Address', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field label
        'placeholder' => __('Confirm Email Address', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field placeholder
        'required'    => true, // if field is required or not
        'clear'       => false, // add clear or not
        'type'        => 'text', // add field type
        'class'       => array('form-row form-row-wide'),   // add class name

    );

    $fields['account']['user_password_again'] = array(
        'label'       => __('Confirm Password', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field label
        'placeholder' => __('Confirm Password', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field placeholder
        'required'    => true, // if field is required or not
        'clear'       => false, // add clear or not
        'type'        => 'text', // add field type
        'class'       => array('form-row form-row-wide'),   // add class name
    );
    
    return $fields;
}
```

I added above code in function.php file and i am using the woocommerce_checkout_fields filter hook to display the filed in checkout form.

How Can i display this custom Dob field in checkout page.
Please help me on this.

Comment: **1)** Instead of mentioning which hook you have used with each piece of code, post your code immediately including the hook so that we can test your code easily without having to make any changes first. **2)** 
In the database you have `customer_dob` and for the checkout page `$fields['billing']['reg_customer_dob']`. `reg_customer_dob` 
is not the same as `customer_dob`, there is the mistake

Comment: @7uc1f3r i added complete code in question.

Comment: Thanks @7uc1f3r for your reply. i need to keep same name for usermeta field & html field name.I am checking this & update here ASAP.

Comment: Thank you @7uc1f3r for your valuable suggestion. It is working and dob is now displaying in checkout page. Can you please explain to me how it is working. Or what I had guessed that user meta field and html form field should be same, they are correct.

Comment: When saving your field you have `update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'customer_dob', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['reg_customer_dob'] ) );`. `customer_dob`
is then written to the database as a metakey and not `reg_customer_dob`. 
In itself it is allowed that you use different values, but then you have to take this into account when further expanding your code